# Status: 500 Internal Server Error org.jruby.RubyModule.getConstant(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/jruby/runtime/builtin/IRubyObject;

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, jruby

I am supporting an old Rails app. It uses Rails version 2.3.2 and JRuby 1.5.6. I am running it in IntelliJ 12. When starting the app or starting the debugger I got this error. I wonder if anyone has seen similar error before and what could possibly caused this. Thanks!

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on ht tp://127.0.0.1:3000
D:/AppDev/WarManager/vendor/gems/logging-0.9.7/lib/logging/config/configurator.rb:133 warning: `instance_eval' should not be aliased
D:/AppDev/WarManager/vendor/gems/logging-0.9.7/lib/logging/layouts/pattern.rb:121 warning: already initialized constant DIRECTIVE_TABLE
D:/AppDev/WarManager/vendor/gems/logging-0.9.7/lib/logging/layouts/pattern.rb:142 warning: already initialized constant DIRECTIVE_RGXP
D:/AppDev/WarManager/vendor/gems/logging-0.9.7/lib/logging/layouts/pattern.rb:145 warning: already initialized constant ISO8601
Logging to: D:/logs/log4j/warManager-development.log
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

>

```
[FATAL] 2014-01-16 10:59:23 [3580] [0.9.7/lib/logging/logger.rb:111]:: /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Jan 16 10:59:23 -0400 2014
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  org.jruby.RubyModule.getConstant(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/jruby/runtime/builtin/IRubyObject;
    arjdbc.ArJdbcModule.modules(ArJdbcModule.java:158)
    arjdbc.ArJdbcModule$s_method_0_0$RUBYINVOKER$modules.call(arjdbc/ArJdbcModule$s_method_0_0$RUBYINVOKER$modules.gen:65535)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:289)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:108)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:61)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    org.jruby.ast.AttrAssignTwoArgNode.interpret(AttrAssignTwoArgNode.java:36)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:119)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:283)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:214)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:359)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:237)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:242)
    org.jruby.RubyClass$SpecificArityNew.call(RubyClass.java:830)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:202)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:349)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:228)
    org.jruby.ast.CallThreeArgNode.interpret(CallThreeArgNode.java:61)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:201)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:546)
    org.jruby.RubyObject.send(RubyObject.java:1443)
    org.jruby.RubyObject$i_method_multi$RUBYINVOKER$send.call(org/jruby/RubyObject$i_method_multi$RUBYINVOKER$send.gen:65535)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrOneOrTwoOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:283)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:329)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:188)
    org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:158)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:289)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:108)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:85)
    org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:158)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:289)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:108)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:85)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:117)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:119)
    org.jruby.ast.DAsgnNode.interpret(DAsgnNode.java:110)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:373)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:346)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:194)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop_1_9(RubyKernel.java:1251)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$loop_1_9.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$loop_1_9.gen:65535)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:299)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:117)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:132)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:373)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:294)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:228)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:99)
    org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:160)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:166)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:81)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:299)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:117)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:122)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:158)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:289)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:108)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:85)
    org.jruby.ast.AttrAssignTwoArgNode.interpret(AttrAssignTwoArgNode.java:36)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:119)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:158)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:289)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:108)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:61)
    org.jruby.ast.AndNode.interpret(AndNode.java:94)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.OrNode.interpret(OrNode.java:94)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:158)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:289)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:108)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:85)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:158)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:289)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:108)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:85)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockPassNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockPassNode.java:53)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:119)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:160)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:166)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:299)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:117)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:122)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.ToAryNode.interpret(ToAryNode.java:69)
    org.jruby.ast.MultipleAsgnNode.interpret(MultipleAsgnNode.java:127)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.ToAryNode.interpret(ToAryNode.java:69)
    org.jruby.ast.MultipleAsgnNode.interpret(MultipleAsgnNode.java:127)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:199)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:118)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:373)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:346)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:194)
    org.jruby.libraries.ThreadLibrary$Mutex.synchronize(ThreadLibrary.java:195)
    org.jruby.libraries.ThreadLibrary$Mutex$i_method_0_0$RUBYINVOKER$synchronize.call(org/jruby/libraries/ThreadLibrary$Mutex$i_method_0_0$RUBYINVOKER$synchronize.gen:65535)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:299)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:117)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:122)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.ReturnNode.interpret(ReturnNode.java:92)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:373)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:346)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:194)
    org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1630)
    org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1637)
    org.jruby.RubyArray$i_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$each.call(org/jruby/RubyArray$i_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$each.gen:65535)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:299)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:117)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:122)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.ToAryNode.interpret(ToAryNode.java:69)
    org.jruby.ast.MultipleAsgnNode.interpret(MultipleAsgnNode.java:127)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.ToAryNode.interpret(ToAryNode.java:69)
    org.jruby.ast.MultipleAsgnNode.interpret(MultipleAsgnNode.java:127)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.ToAryNode.interpret(ToAryNode.java:69)
    org.jruby.ast.MultipleAsgnNode.interpret(MultipleAsgnNode.java:127)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:221)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:329)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:188)
    org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:373)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:346)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:194)
    org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1630)
    org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1637)
    org.jruby.RubyArray$i_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$each.call(org/jruby/RubyArray$i_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$each.gen:65535)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:299)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:117)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:122)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:117)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:117)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.WhileNode.interpret(WhileNode.java:131)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:199)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:118)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:180)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:174)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:309)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:373)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:327)
    org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:78)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:89)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:224)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:207)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:94)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use an "older" version on AR-JDBC (**activerecord-jdbc-adapter** gem) if you're on JRuby 1.5 ... **1.3** needs at least JRuby 1.6 and the latest of the **1.2** release might as well - try downgrading until you hit something that works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried version 9.0 and 9.2, the error was gone. How can you tell this is an activerecord-jdbc-adapter issue from the error message?

Comment: cause I understand the internals ( of its "native" Java API :)